# Partial refresh fires the addOnLoad event in XPage

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

In my XPage I have an `addOnLoad` written in my script block. But the thing is that it fires even during partial refresh which I don't want. For e.g. if I have a pager control on a data table then clicking on pages fires the `addOnLoad` function. This happens with both `dojo.addOnLoad` and `XSP.addOnLoad`.

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    console.log("addOnLoad");
});
```

This would print 'addOnLoad' every time a partial refresh takes place. I even tried to modify the code this way but no luck.

```
var addOnLoadFired = false;
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    if (addOnLoadFired) {
        return;
    }
    addOnLoadFired = true;
    console.log("addOnLoad");
});
```

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Move your script block out of area which is partially refreshed.

Comment: I don't think that would be the reason. The example I have is that I created a data table and a pager control associated with it. When switch between pages using pager control the `addOnLoad` executes. And the script block does not reside in data table.

Comment: Hack solution: when the code runs the first time, write something to the viewScope and check that before running the code?

Comment: @AaronBrake: But `viewScope` is SSJS and my code is client side JavaScript.

Comment: Could write a value to a hidden field then and check that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing a partial refresh without specifying a refresh id, the whole XPage is refreshed. Same happens if you refresh the UIViewRoot element. In both cases this includes your output scriptblock, and that is why your addOnLoad event is fired over and over again.

A pager refreshs his parent component automatically. If your Pager is just added to your XPage, it will always refresh the UIViewRoot.

To fix your problem, you can embedd the dataTable and the pager in a xp:div element. Another idea is to check in the rendered property of your output script block if a partial refresh is executed.

**EDIT:**
Check for partial refresh programmatically (SSJS):

```
var ajax = new com.ibm.xsp.ajax.AjaxUtil();
if( ajax.isAjaxPartialRefresh(facesContext) == true){
    return "AJAX";
}else{
    return "NOT AJAX!"
}
```

Comment: Embedding my data table and pager inside `<xp:div>` did not work. How will I check in the `rendered` property that page has been partially refreshed?

Comment: You can see it in Firebug or other developer tools in IE/Chrome - look into Network section after refresh. Response contains either whole page (ful refresh) or just part of the html for partially refreshed component. That was my comment about: if you move script out of refreshed html, it won't run. As Sven pointed out, you seem to have full refresh instead.

Comment: @Naveen: have you set the id of the div?

Comment: @SvenHasselbach: I set the ID of `<xp:div>` and it worked. Thanks a ton! :)